# React Native - pass data between views

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile-development

I built a basic app in React Native.

I implemented the Navigator object and I can push a view to another view.

A few questions:
1. How do I pass data from the 2nd view to the 1st view when the 2nd view is dismissed?
2. How do I know that the 1st view gained focus again? I added listeners in the Navigator so the Navigator knows about the "willfocus" but the navigator can't communicate with the view...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where are your doing that in iOS or Android ?

Comment: @PravinTate - I'm doing that for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- As far as passing data to the second view after the first has been dismissed, you're probably going to need something like Redux or Flux. Another way would be to pass down a function as props that takes a value from the second component.

2- Have you tried this

```
this.props.navigator.navigationContext.addListener('willfocus', callback)
```

Comment: As for 1- I'll check
As for 2- I added a listener to the navigator. So now the navigator knows that there is a 'willfocus' event tied to the navigationContext. How does it help me? The navigator does not know which view was updated and the view does not know that the listener was called...

Comment: Glad it worked. You're right, I should have included more code! :/ Glad you figured it out though...